# Iterate through a nested listed to fetch a Key Value Pair

Tags: python

I have really struggled to write code for this problem:

My data is as follows:

```
all_records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.',
                                        u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}],
                                        u'TTL': 300,
                                        u'Type': 'A'},
                                       {u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com',
                                        u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}],
                                        u'TTL': 300,
                                        u'Type': 'A'}]}
```

I want to iterate through this list to find Value when Name is `dev1.abc.com`

I don't want to define a new function, I just want to do this in couple of for loops.

Comment: Actually you **should** want to define a new function - but anyway, can you update your question to show the code you have written so far?

Comment: Also, it would help if you formatted your code so the structure of your data is more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with list comprehension:

```
all_records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.',
                                        u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}],
                                        u'TTL': 300,
                                        u'Type': 'A'},
                                       {u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com',
                                        u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}],
                                        u'TTL': 300,
                                        u'Type': 'A'}]}
value = [e['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value'] for e in all_records['ResourceRecordSets'] if e['Name']=="dev1.abc.com."]
value
```

`value` will be:

```
['10.0.3.214']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, maybe you want to format the values differently:

```
desired_name = 'dev1.abc.com'
values = []
for resource in all_records['ResourceRecordSets']:
    if resource['Name'] != desired_name:
        continue
    values = [record['Value'] for record in resource['ResourceRecords']]
    break

print(values)
```

Same logic but with @quamrana's suggestion:

```
desired_name = 'dev1.abc.com'
values = []
for resource in all_records['ResourceRecordSets']:
    if resource['Name'] == desired_name:
        values = [record['Value'] for record in resource['ResourceRecords']]
        break

print(values)
```

Comment: Paco H, I think you should invert your test for `desired_name` to make simpler code.

Comment: @quamrana thanks for your comment, I added your suggestion as another option. I personally prefer the way I did it, but it comes down to personal taste.

Comment: Paco H, Thanks for including my suggestion. My personal taste is to have less lines of code and in this case to move the action of extracting values closer to the decision about which record to select.

Comment: Of course :) For me I prefer the least indentation, i.e. each new level of indentation means you have to keep track of one more state of the program in your head in order to understand what's going on. Having said that, in this simple case, your suggestion might be clearer than mine, even from my point of view.

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-107 components]$ python test.py
[]
Am I missing something ? Is the 'if' statement placed around right list ?

Comment: @rashcuva Did you fix the typo `dev1.abc.com.` -> `dev1.abc.com` (the extra dot at the end)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a typo but you actually have a dot at the end of `dev1.abc.com.`

```
all_records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.', u'TTL': 300}, {u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com', u'TTL': 300}]}

name = 'dev1.abc.com.'
for x in all_records['ResourceRecordSets']:
    if x['Name'] == name:
        value = x['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value']

print(value)
# 10.0.3.214
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler. No break statement required.

`for i in range(len(all_records['ResourceRecordSets'])):
    if(all_records['ResourceRecordSets'][i]['Name']== 'dev1.abc.com.'):
        print all_records['ResourceRecordSets'][i]['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value']`

Comment: This only works if there is exactly one record in  `all_records['ResourceRecordSets'][i]['ResourceRecords']` for every `i`. @paco-h provided a solution which works for any number of records.

Comment: I agree but this is what is required for this particular question. For n number of values in `all_records['ResourceRecordSets'][i]['ResourceRecords']`, it is trivial to include another loop to account for all possible values.

Comment: As the data obviously consists of DNS records (ie. `Name` is FQDN and `Value` contains IP addresses) it is entirely possible that it is just a happenstance that the sample does not contain multiple values per name. DNS allows many IP addresses for a single FQDN, so I would take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [10]: new = list(filter(lambda x: x[u'Name'] == 'dev1.abc.com.', all_records[u'ResourceRecordSets']))[0]['ResourceRecords']

In [11]: new
Out[11]: [{'Value': '10.0.3.214'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use high-level functions:

- Assuming there may be multiple `"Value"` dictionaries inside `"ResourceRecords"` and that there may be several `"Name"` occurrences.

  ```
  records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.', u'TTL': 300}, {u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com', u'TTL': 300}]}

  name_to_find = "dev1.abc.com."
  return_values = map(lambda sub_dict: [sub_list["Value"] for sub_list in sub_dict["ResourceRecords"]],
                      filter(lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["Name"] == name_to_find,
                             records["ResourceRecordSets"]))

  print(list(return_dicts))
  ```
- In case there is only one `"Value"` dictionary inside `"ResourceRecords"` and that there may be several `"Name"` occurrences.

  ```
  records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.', u'TTL': 300}, {u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com', u'TTL': 300}]}

  name_to_find = "dev1.abc.com."
  return_values = map(lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["ResourceRecords"][0]["Value"],
                      filter(lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["Name"] == name_to_find,
                             records["ResourceRecordSets"]))

  print(list(return_dicts))
  ```
- If there is only one `"Name"` occurrence you are better off using a `for each` loop with a break:

  ```
  records = {u'ResourceRecordSets': [{u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.214'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev1.abc.com.', u'TTL': 300}, {u'ResourceRecords': [{u'Value': '10.0.3.67'}], u'Type': 'A', u'Name': 'dev2.abc.com', u'TTL': 300}]}

  name_to_find = 'dev1.abc.com.'
  return_values = []
  for sub_dict in records['ResourceRecordSets']:
      if sub_dict['Name'] == name_to_find:
          return_values = [record['Value'] for record in sub_dict['ResourceRecords']]
          break
  ```

Comment: OP has specifically asked for `Value`, not for the whole sub-dict.